# Branch filters not working on Build Completion trigger in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I currently have both a `ci` and `publish` pipeline set up in Azure DevOps. The `ci` pipeline runs in every branch on every commit. I would like the `publish` pipeline to run on `ci` completion, but only against the `develop` branch.

On the Triggers on the `publish` pipeline, I currently have the following set:
[image]

I would expect this to run `publish` after `ci` completion on the `develop` branch only. However, after `ci` completes it kicks off `publish` against the `master` branch instead. Why is the branch filter I have set up above allowing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the same Build completion settings on my side, it works well. The `publish` pipeline will not be triggered after the CI build triggered by the master branch of the `ci` pipeline is completed.

You can check the run record of the `publish` pipeline to see if the triggered build is due to `Build completion`.

[image]

Comment: After reviewing in depth last night, I found that the branch filter was indeed working. However, the publish pipeline was targeting the master branch, not the develop branch. Once I changed that, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Is it possible to have this work on branches in folders?  For example, when selecting Build completion as the trigger, the Branch filters section allows entering releases/* as an included branch specification.  The problem is, this doesn't work because when this build runs, it builds from master.  I need it to build from the new branch in releases/.  The build that this one relies on has "enable continusous integration" checked, with the same branch filter.